# Angular 4 auxiliary route with component opens md-dialog throws error at server side rendering

Tags: angular, angular-material2

So, I have an angular app and using `md-dialog` for modal purpose. Everything working fine but it throws error server-side rendering when try to open auxiliary route. I tried `AfterViewInit` but it did not work. I thought it must open the component defined in route config, and then execute `dialog.open()` method in `ngAfterViewInit` method.

This is relevant route config :

```
{
  path: 'postm/:postId',
  component: PostIndexModalComponent,   
  outlet:'post'
},
```

This is the PostIndexModalComponent that opens md-dialog

```
export class PostIndexModalComponent implements OnInit,OnDestroy,AfterViewInit{

post: any
isAuthorizedSubscription: Subscription;
isAuthorized: boolean;
postId: number;
urlSub: any;

constructor(public dialog: MdDialog,public router:Router,public activatedRoute:ActivatedRoute) { }
ngOnInit() {
    this.urlSub = this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.postId = params['postId'];            
    });

}
ngOnDestroy() {


}
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.openModal();
}

openModal() {
    console.log(this.postId);
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(PostModalComponent, {
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
        panelClass:'da',
        data: {
            postId:this.postId
        }
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(f => {
        this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { post: null } }]);
    });

}

closeModal($event) {
    this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { post: null } }]);
}
}
```

Auxulary route works in client-side well but, server side rendering gives error:

> NodeInvocationException: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: document is not defined
>   ReferenceError: document is not defined
>   at Overlay._createPaneElement (C:\Users\doom\Desktop\feasion\fso.Web\fso.AngularClient\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:11465:46)
>   at Overlay.create (C:\Users\doom\Desktop\feasion\fso.Web\fso.AngularClient\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:11450:44)
>   at MdDialog._createOverlay (C:\Users\doom\Desktop\feasion\fso.Web\fso.AngularClient\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:26492:30)
>   at MdDialog.open (C:\Users\doom\Desktop\feasion\fso.Web\fso.AngularClient\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:26460:48)
>   at PostIndexModalComponent.openModal (C:\Users\doom\Desktop\feasion\fso.Web\fso.AngularClient\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:65986:37)
>   at PostIndexModalComponent.ngAfterViewInit (C:\Users\doom\Desktop\feasion\fso.Web\fso.AngularClient\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:65981:14)
>   at callProviderLifecycles (C:\Users\doom\Desktop\feasion\fso.Web\fso.AngularClient\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:22011:18)
>   at callElementProvidersLifecycles (C:\Users\doom\Desktop\feasion\fso.Web\fso.AngularClient\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:21986:13)
>   at callLifecycleHooksChildrenFirst (C:\Users\doom\Desktop\feasion\fso.Web\fso.AngularClient\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:21970:17)
>   at Object.checkAndUpdateView (C:\Users\doom\Desktop\feasion\fso.Web\fso.AngularClient\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:23002:5)
>   Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: document is not defined

Comment: From the error it seems like one of the components used tries to use the `document` object, which is not defined in the server-context (`document` makes sense in the browser).  Have you looked for similar errors in the Angular Material github issues board?

Comment: Yes md-dialog component uses document but why ngAfterViewInit() executing in server side?